# boost::uint32_t != std::uint32_t for ARM target

Tags: c++, boost, arm

The following program fails to compile when cross-compiling from OS X to ARM:

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<std::uint32_t, boost::uint32_t>::value, "");

int main() { }
```

I'm building with

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -I /path/to/boost -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
```

where

```
> arm-none-eabi-g++ --version
arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529 (release) 
[ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288]
```

To try and diagnose the issue further, I tried the following trick:

```
template <typename T> struct show;
using A = show<std::uint32_t>::invalid;
using B = show<boost::uint32_t>::invalid;
```

The compiler gives me the following error message, which indicates that `std::uint32_t == long unsigned int`, while `boost::uint32_t == unsigned int`:

```
main.cpp:8:32: error: 'invalid' in 'struct show<long unsigned int>' does not name a type
 using A = show<std::uint32_t>::invalid;
                                ^
main.cpp:9:34: error: 'invalid' in 'struct show<unsigned int>' does not name a type
 using B = show<boost::uint32_t>::invalid;
```

I find this situation very surprising. Shouldn't `uint32_t` always represent exactly the same type (a 32-bit width unsigned integer), regardless of the system on which we are? Is this a bug in Boost or simply me misunderstanding something?

Comment: Multiple types may be able to represent a 32-bit unsigned integer. That's just an aspect of C++ you have to live with.

Comment: _"Shouldn't `uint32_t` always represent exactly the same type (a 32-bit width unsigned integer), regardless of the system on which we are?"_ N.B. it isn't even required to exist on all systems! It only exists on systems where there is a type of exactly 32 bits. `uint_least32_t` always exists, but might be larger than 32 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint32_t` should always represent a 32-bit width unsigned integer, yes.

But it's perfectly possible for `sizeof(long unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned int)` to be true. Those are two different types that can have the same width.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Then, I think it is simply a QOI issue in Boost that `boost::uint32_t` isn't always the same as `std::uint32_t`, since it makes it more difficult to interoperate between both.

Comment: For reference, I followed up on the [Boost.Devel](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/264335) mailing list regarding this issue.

Comment: Other than explicit specialization not matching, and mangling, what is the problem you are facing?  @louisdionne

Comment: @Yakk An invalid conversion from some function pointer `void (*)(boost::uint32_t)` to `void (*)(std::uint32_t)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that two 32 bit unsigned integer values are the same type.

In fact, `long` and `int` can be distinct types, and both can be 32 bit values, at the same time.  Ditto for `wchar_t` and `short` being 16 bit values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll accept orlp's answer because it came first, but yours is equally good.